# send form with upload file in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajaxform, jquery-upload-file-plugin

i use busbody to upload file in nodejs 
i can upload file but i cant get text message in bodyparser
 my fornt end code is :

```
<script>
    $("input[type='button']").click(function(){
    var files = $("input[type='file']").get();

    var formData = new FormData();
    var text  = "xxxxx";
    var url  = "fileUpload";
    if (files.length > 0){
      for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var input = $("input[type='file']").get(i).files;
        var file = input;
        if(file.length>0){
          console.log( file[0].name);
          formData.append('userpic',file[0], file[0].name);
        }
      }
      formData.append('text',text);
      $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: url,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        data: formData, // serializes the form's elements.
      });
    }
  });
</script>
```

server.js

```
router.post('/fileUpload', function(req, res) {
console.log(req.body.text);
// req.pipe(req.busboy);
req.busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename) {
    console.log('ok2');
    var fstream = fs.createWriteStream('./public/images/' + filename);
    file.pipe(fstream);
    fstream.on('close', function () {

    });
});
res.send('upload succeeded!');
});
```

this line of code console.log(req.body.text);
just return {}

Comment: Can you post your app.js file code?

Comment: @abdulbarik
var bodyParser   = require('body-parser');
var busboy = require('connect-busboy');
app.use(busboy());
app.use(bodyParser());
i use middelware in app.js

Answer (score 1):

Try using body-parser:

`npm install --save body-parser`

and then select middleware:

`var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());`

Or use the middleware directly:

`var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
router.post('/fileUpload', bodyParser.json(), function(req, res) {....});`

Also try using `console.log(req.body)` to look at format of the request.

Comment: i use middelware in app.js

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because of this line: `file.pipe(fstream);`, this should be  `fstream.pipe(file)`.

And like Steven say multer is a good alternative.